# How to avoid loss of accuracy when converting symbolic expressions to functions?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

**tl;dr:** I observe a complete loss of accuracy when converting a symbolic expression to a function handle with `matlabFunction`. I wonder if there are ways to improve the conversion in order to avoid the loss of accuracy.

---

I have a symbolic variable `x` for which `1 <= x && x <= 2` holds true:

```
syms x real
assumeAlso(1 <= x & x <= 2);
```

I have many computer-generated, lengthy symbolic expression in that variable. One of them looks like this:

```
expression = ( ...
  1015424780204960143215273323910078528628754663952913658657288835138029704791686717561885487746105223164496264397062144000 ...
  *( ...
     60345244216851610523130575942127473698515638085026410114070496399315754724985170479034760688327679099512793302302720*2^(1/2) ...
   - 85341062796188128379389251264141456937242003828816791711306294886439805159655912635773490018204138847163921224639041 ...
   )*(x - 2)^2 ...
) ...
/31504288346872372712061562812941419427167561153216213605146864117586323331155800294021400857537041202039565879856190821729945216935526707438840242294801134287960934949194864204307116208568439380511702602881;
```

**Edit:** You have to construct it with (pasting the above will make `expression` a constant 0)

```
expression = sym('(1015424780204960143215273323910078528628754663952913658657288835138029704791686717561885487746105223164496264397062144000*(60345244216851610523130575942127473698515638085026410114070496399315754724985170479034760688327679099512793302302720*2^(1/2) - 85341062796188128379389251264141456937242003828816791711306294886439805159655912635773490018204138847163921224639041)*(x - 2)^2)/31504288346872372712061562812941419427167561153216213605146864117586323331155800294021400857537041202039565879856190821729945216935526707438840242294801134287960934949194864204307116208568439380511702602881');
```

Calling `double(subs(expression, x, 1))` evaluates this expression to approximately `-5.9492e+03` without any problems, which actually is the correct value. However, the evaluation takes far too long and is a huge (or rather tiny?) bottleneck in my application. That’s why I intend to convert the expression to an anonymous function that operates on doubles and is much faster, like so:

```
evaluator = matlabFunction(expression, 'Vars', x);
```

The result being

```
@(x) (sqrt(2.0).*6.034524421685161e115-8.534106279618813e115) ...
.*(x-2.0).^2.*3.223131940086397e-86
```

I had much success with this approach in the past. Unfortunately in this case, `evaluator(x)` evaluates to 0 for any value of *x*, because the first row is exactly zero. Obviously, this has to do with the limited number of significant digits for doubles.

Are there ways to work around this? Can I tell MATLAB to consider the range of `x` so that it can find a better representation of the constants?

Comment: I'm curious what application needs numbers 206 digits long! I can't replicate your results, from the code you provided, on 2015b, `double(subs(expression, x, 1)) = 0`

Comment: `double(subs(expression, x, 1))` returns 0 too for me.

Comment: Additionally, have you tried turning off code optimization with `matlabFunction` (see documentation)?

Comment: @Wolfie I actually don’t need nor want these long numbers. They are the result of some simple linear algebra involving symbolic variables.

Comment: @m7913d: Interesting, I, too, get 0 for this example. The actual expression I’m working with is exactly the same, only the variable has a different name. Looking into this…

Comment: @horchler No optimizations are performed when converting an expression to an *anonymous* function. Optimizations can be enabled only when you write the function to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be fixed with [variable-precision arithmetic](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html):

```
>> expr = vpa(expression)
expr =
-5949.2156936801140978790460880789*(x - 2.0)^2
```

Convert it to a function

```
>> func =
  function_handle with value:
    @(x)(x-2.0).^2.*-5.949215693680114e3
```

Then evaluate it

```
>> func(1)
ans =
  -5.9492e+03
```